Regex to ignore string before end line
I have CSV files that look like this:
"08d43c37-9b43-4030-b1db-558f8bc89d52","0007661355","cus_7luwjohxnnlujhwinhvhtmzc4y","chandler.kwek@sweetmag.com.my",""Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek"","08d43c37-9b43-4030-b1db-558f8bc89d52","src_mh255jar4y2eta6jfpgmocgqda","379186","0144","22","08","9A1219C06AEFEA42097ABE1E2911B5579C61E51BBB720FF658B35822B336E840",""

My job is to load them into a database table but the customer name is incorrectly formatted. With my sed expression
sed -E 's/"{2}/"/g;t' <<< file.csv

, I can change
,""Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek"",

into this
,"Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek",

The problem is this strips the ,"" at the end of my line into ," and breaks my load. That rightmost field is empty 90% of the time and surrounded by double-quotes, but there's occasionally data.
I tried adding a negative lookahead like so but it doesn't work:
sed -E 's/"{2}(?!^,""$)/"/g;t' <<< file.csv

I think the issue lies in how I do my substitution. What should my regex be to ignore the ,"" at the end of each record?

Not being familar with sed, afaik there are no lookarounds available: 1.) If there is always a word character bordering to "" at the left or right, try to replace ""\b|\b"" with ". 2.) Use capture groups, search for ""(.*?)"" and replace with "\1".

I just noticed my second idea does not work due to lack of lazy quantifier support. You would need to use negation instead: ""([^"]*)"" (and replace with "\1") if this works with your data.

It works great here but also fails on MacOs with RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid -- changed regex to sed -E 's/"+(?!$)/"/g;t' *0.csv -- no luck

Rather than swim against the current, just restore the trailing double quotes after the removal process:
sed -E 's/"{2}/"/g;t' | sed -E 's/,"$/,""/'


This:
echo '"foo",""Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek"",""' | sed -E 's/"{2}/"/g;t' | sed -E 's/,"$/,""/'

produces:
"foo","Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek",""


It fails on MacOs with RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

@CB  If you need help with mac specific problems, you'll do better to post your questions to [apple.se] . Good luck.

@CB I ran this on a Mac, so it does work. FYI I'm on v 14.4.1 build 23E224, shell /bin/zsh

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/"\("[^"]*"\)"/\1/g' file

Look for pairs of double double quotes and remove the outer double quotes.
If double quotes can be quoted between double quotes then use:
sed -E 's/"("([^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"])*)*")"/\1/g' file

Which allows for one or more quoted characters between double double quotes.

Using any POSIX awk, this will fix problematic fields like ""foo"" but protect empty fields like "" anywhere they occur in the input, not just at the end of a line:
$ awk '{$0=","$0","; while(gsub(/,"",/,",\n,")); gsub(/""/,"\""); while(gsub(/,\n,/,",\"\",")); gsub(/^,|,$/,""); print}' file.csv
"08d43c37-9b43-4030-b1db-558f8bc89d52","0007661355","cus_7luwjohxnnlujhwinhvhtmzc4y","chandler.kwek@sweetmag.com.my","Chandler, Huang Kun Kwek","08d43c37-9b43-4030-b1db-558f8bc89d52","src_mh255jar4y2eta6jfpgmocgqda","379186","0144","22","08","9A1219C06AEFEA42097ABE1E2911B5579C61E51BBB720FF658B35822B336E840",""

It turns every "" that's between commas or at the start/end of the line (i.e. is simply an empty field) into newlines to protect them from the next step, then converts any remaining ""s (i.e. the problematic ones within fields) into "s, then converts the newlines back to ""s.
For example, using a modified input file that contains more empty fields that need to be protected and additional bad fields in various positions to show they get fixed:
$ cat file.csv
"","","","good field",""bad field"","also good","",""
""bad again"","","still good",""bad field"","really good","",""also bad""


$ awk '{$0=","$0","; while(gsub(/,"",/,",\n,")); gsub(/""/,"\""); while(gsub(/,\n,/,",\"\",")); gsub(/^,|,$/,""); print}' file.csv
"","","","good field","bad field","also good","",""
"bad again","","still good","bad field","really good","","also bad"

